# Long text in a visually appealing fashion?

Tags: html, css, layout

As you can see on the picture below, my text is displayed within a 'relatively small' DIV. Currently users have the possibility to scroll down within the DIV to read the full text but I don't really like that solution and I'm looking for something more visually appealing.
What would you advise in this case? Something like hide/show DIVs when users click on "text part 2", "text part 3, etc?
Many thanks
[image]

Comment: ummm... that's the reason scrolling was invented in the first place.... also, this probably belongs on [ux.se]

Answer (score 1):

Use the jqueryui accordion widget http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/
Bootstrap also has one
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the bootstrap accordion, I think it looks better than the jqueryui one, you need to download bootstrap to make this work

Answer (score 1):

Make the text area work more like a book flipping a page--like a nook reading interface.

Check out these jquery examples: [Examples/Ideas](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/)

Check out this HTML5 example: [Examples/Ideas](http://www.turnjs.com/)